# setting default working directory to project folder in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, projects-and-solutions

When I open my R project from the project folder, the default working directory is not my project folder.
I thought it should, by default, set the working directory to the project folder. I know how to set the working directory but I need to setup r studio so that my R projects open with the project folder as the default working directory.

Comment: your working directory will be the directory where R project file `*.Rproj` is present. Isn't it not the case?

Comment: How are you verifying what your current working directory is?

Comment: @abhiieor No, it is not the case. but it is what I expected.

Comment: @MrFlick the current working directory is written on  top of the console, its what I get when I run `getwd()`

Comment: And are you opening the project with "file...open project" or double clicking on the project file in your file explorer? What OS are you running?

Comment: @MrFlick I running this on windows and it does not matter whether I open with "file...open project" or double-click on the project file in my file explorer. it does not default to the project folder.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that creating an `.Rprofile` file for each project and store it in the same folder as the `Rproj`file works. Thanks to this
https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/
website about efficient R programming. Only that it means I have to create the `.Rprofile` file myself every time I create a new project. This is however better than having to set the working directory manually making my projects non-portable.

Comment: link is broken as of today